# Room databasebuilder not enough information to infer type variable T

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm new in room database and I have problem with `Room.databasebuilder` that shown an error **not enough information to infer type variable T**.

Here is my code

```
@Database(entities = [ThreadTable::class, GambarThreadTable::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ThreadDb: RoomDatabase() {
    companion object{
        private var instance: ThreadDb? = null

        fun getDb(context: Context): ThreadDb{
            if (instance == null){
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, ThreadDb::class.java, "ThreadDb")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as ThreadDb
        }
    }

    abstract fun daoThread() : DaoThread
}
```

Room version

```
    def room_version = "2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

The error occurs on `ThreadDb::class.java`, what should I change ? I have checked and tried some tutorials but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and did not get any error.
Alternatively, you could try something like this:

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [ThreadTable::class, GambarThreadTable::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class ThreadDb : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun daoThread(): DaoThread

    companion object {

        private val sLockObject = Object()

        @Volatile
        private lateinit var INSTANCE: ThreadDb

        fun getInstance(context: Context): ThreadDb {
            if (!isInitialized()) {
                synchronized(sLockObject) {
                    val name = "ThreadDb"
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context, ThreadDb::class.java, name)
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build().also { instance -> INSTANCE = instance }
                }

            }
            
            return INSTANCE
        }

        private fun isInitialized() = ::INSTANCE.isInitialized
    }
}
```

Comment: still can't sir, I guess something wrong with my plugins

Comment: `@Volatile` unresolved reference, `synchronized` and `databaseBuilder` are reds too

Comment: Looks like an import issue to me, are you importing correct classes?

Comment: yes of course, `databaseBuilder` is still with the same problem

Comment: Have you added `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler"` to your dependencies?

Comment: yes already added it